# Cut command with delimiter Control-A

Tags: shell, cut

I am trying to get some columns from file1 to file2 using cut command with delimiter Control A.

This is what I tried:

```
cut -d^A -f2-8 a.dat > b.dat
```

If my records are like this:

```
A^AB^AC^AD^AE^AF^AG^AH^A$
```

my command gives:

```
AB^AC^AD^AE^AF^AG^AH
```

Is my command wrong or am I putting the delimiter in a wrong way?

So it leaves Control-A's A in the starting point.

Comment: Works fine for me, provided that all your `^A` are proper Control-A's, e.g. entered via the sequence Ctrl+V; Ctrl+A (including in your command line, of course). Maybe check directly the `hexdump` of your file, where Control-A's are 0x01.

Comment: Can you show output of `cat -vte a.dat`

Answer (score 16):

`^A` is character number 1 in the ASCII table  a.k.a `Start of Heading` character. If you're using bash, you can have this:

```
cut -f 2-8 -d $'\x01'
```

Or use `printf` (can be builtin or an external binary):

```
CTRL_A=$(printf '\x01')
cut -f 2-8 -d "$CTRL_A"
```

You can also verify your output with `hexdump`:

```
hexdump -C b.dat
```

Comment: No need to know the ASCII value of Control-A; `-d $'\cA'` should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand your question, but would suggest you use `tr` to change your Control-As into something else more workable and maybe then change them back when you are finished:

```
tr '^A' ',' < yourfile | do some cutting using commas | tr ',' '^A' > newfile
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the control character might have been chosen precisely _because_ commas (and other non-control characters) can be present in the fields. In other words, if choosing the approach from this answer, make sure that the "more workable" character is absent from the fields it's supposed to separate.